# reading XML File from URL in Android

Tags: java, android

I experimented with several ways of opening an XML file from the link, but all the roads did not do any good.
In order to make sure that parsing XML File is good, I downloaded the file and put it in Asset folder to make parsing all of this good.
We can deduce from this the error in reading from url

URL is http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url.toString());
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
InputStream in=response.getEntity().getContent();
```

OR

```
HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
InputStream in=con.getInputStream();
```

OR

```
InputStream in =url.openStream();
```

please help me

My Problem solved thanx to all for your help.I should use AsyncTask class when i get File from Url

Comment: no one of this method is right

Comment: Wow....so Should I assume you are inventing new way to make web call? BTW, you should read: [Android’s HTTP Clients](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)

Comment: What is the problem that you are having?  Is there an exception whose stack trace you could post?  Also, did you set the proper permissions in your manifest.xml file?

Comment: my problem is not in permission

Comment: If you have already solved your problem (Grats :D) then please answer to your own question and mark it answered. Prevents others from getting a headache :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void xmlReader() {

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml");

            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(url
                    .openStream()));

            nodlist = document.getElementsByTagName("Youritem");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nodlist.item(i);

                NodeList nodlistid = element.getElementsByTagName("Id");
                Element id = (Element) nodlistid.item(0);


                NodeList nodlistBaslik = element.getElementsByTagName("tagname1");
                Element baslik = (Element) nodlistBaslik.item(0);

                NodeList nodlistDetay = element.getElementsByTagName("tagname2");
                Element detay = (Element) nodlistDetay.item(0);

                NodeList nodlistKaynak = element.getElementsByTagName("tagname3");
                Element lat = (Element) nodlistKaynak.item(0);

                NodeList nodelistMedia = element.getElementsByTagName("tagname4");
                Element longi = (Element) nodelistMedia.item(0);

                NodeList nodelistTur = element.getElementsByTagName("tagname5");
                Element tur = (Element) nodelistTur.item(0);
                // String resimURL =
                // resim.getAttributes().getNamedItem("url").getNodeValue();

                NodeList nodelistMedia1 = element.getElementsByTagName("enclosure");    
                Element picture= (Element) nodelistMedia1.item(0);
                String pictureURL = resim.getAttributes().getNamedItem("picturetagname").getNodeValue();    

                xmltagname1.add(tagname1.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                xmltagname2.add(tagname2.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                xmltagname3.add(tagname3.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                xmltagname4.add(tagname4.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                xmltagname5.add(tagname5.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I think this method helps you.. Take it easy

Comment: :( the same error when the program read XML file from url.
 I downloaded the file and put it in Asset folder to make parsing all of this good
my problem is not in parsing ,it's in reading :(

Comment: I guess you should do with **AsyncTask** method.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
  String TextHolder = "", TextHolder2 = "";
public class GetNotePadFileFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String userId = SharedPrefHelper.getPrefsHelper().getPref(SharedPrefHelper.PREF_USER_ID);

        try {
            URL url = new URL(baseUrl+"fileName.xml");
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            while ((TextHolder2 = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                TextHolder += TextHolder2;
            }
            bufferReader.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
            malformedURLException.printStackTrace();
            TextHolder = malformedURLException.toString();

        } catch (IOException iOException) {
            iOException.printStackTrace();
            TextHolder = iOException.toString();
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void finalTextHolder) {
        Document doc = convertStringToXMLDocument( TextHolder );
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(ApiConstant.ApiKeys.SMS_MESSAGE);
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                Sms sms = new Sms(
                        eElement.getElementsByTagName(ApiConstant.ApiKeys.SMS_IDS).item(0).getTextContent(),
                        eElement.getElementsByTagName(ApiConstant.ApiKeys.SMS_ADDRESS).item(0).getTextContent(),
                        eElement.getElementsByTagName(ApiConstant.ApiKeys.SMS_BODY).item(0).getTextContent(),
                        eElement.getElementsByTagName(ApiConstant.ApiKeys.SMS_READ).item(0).getTextContent(),
                        eElement.getElementsByTagName(ApiConstant.ApiKeys.SMS_DATE).item(0).getTextContent(),
                        eElement.getElementsByTagName(ApiConstant.ApiKeys.SMS_TYPE).item(0).getTextContent(),
                        false
                );

                LogClass.e("mysms",""+sms.getAddress());
                smsArrayList.add(sms);
            }
        }

        setUi();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(finalTextHolder);
    }

}


  new GetNotePadFileFromServer().execute();
```